# Переключение класса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Идея такова, что нужно по нажатию на дивы prev и next переключать класс active у дивов с классом item-title. Не знаю как это реализовать :(

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item-title active"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item-title"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item-title"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Влево
   Вправо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот таким образом можно сделать то что вы хотели. Просто не знаю как все это объяснить? Если вы знаете `jquery` то код для вас будет понятным. Там нечего сложного не реализовано.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.prev').on('click', function(){
    var active_element = $('.item-title.active');
    if(!active_element.parent().is(':first-child')){
      active_element.parent().prev().find('.item-title').addClass('active');
      active_element.removeClass('active');
    }
    else{
      active_element.removeClass('active');
      $('.item:last-child>.item-title').addClass('active');
    }
  });
  
  $('.next').on('click', function(){
    var active_element = $('.item-title.active');
    if(!active_element.parent().is(':last-child')){
      active_element.parent().next().find('.item-title').addClass('active');
      active_element.removeClass('active');
    }
    else{
      active_element.removeClass('active');
      $('.item:first-child>.item-title').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.item{
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.item-title{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  
}
.item-title.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item-title active"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item-title"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
   <div class="item-title"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="prev">Влево</div>
<div class="next">Вправо</div>
```